# NSXMLparser with basic authentication in IOS swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift, nsxml

We have a web service which needs authentication to fetch XML data.Now I am writing a code in swift to parse this XML request. I am using NSXML parser.
But it is not working with authentication. Where to pass these credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking ,Using AFHTTPRequestOperation u can pass credentials.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"http://188.40.74.207:8888/api/customer" parameters:nil error:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
//[operation setCredential:credential];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"admin" password:@"admin"];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    NSLog(@"Success: %@", [operation responseString]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];
[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];


[manager GET:@"http://188.40.74.207:8888/api/customer" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    arr_Response = responseObject;
    //  NSLog(@"Arr count is: %lu", (unsigned long)arr_Response.count);
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    [self parseData];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Or without using third party you can use below code.

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [self username], [self password]];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",     [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
[theRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Or you can try below code.There is one delegate method of NSURLConnection

```
// NSURLConnection Delegates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USER"
                                                                password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    NSLog(@"credential created");
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");    
}
else {
    NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
}
}
```

Comment: is it not possible in NSXMLparser , without using any external library ?

Comment: thanks !! I managed to do it in swift with ref to your answer